# Knockoutjs nested view model updates

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, nested, viewmodel

I'm trying to understand how I can have nested knockoutjs view models with a little fiddle that lists some items and on click of a button, it shows the details of that item. Then, I have a button that updates the Id property of each item by adding 15 to each ones but for a reason, they end up having all the same value at the end.
Can someone enlighten me?

Thanks!

[The fiddle in question](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BigStef/xunne/27/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `.Name` computed property. The Id change works correctly.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Y3JXD/1/

The `item` in the closure was always the last `item` in the list after the first execution. Remember that the computed is updated any time the observable changes. So, the first time during setup, it worked fine as `item` was the `item` from the loop. But, what was captured in the closure was just `item` (the 15th item), not the one that was for that specific loop instance.

**Update**: forgot about the second parameter to computed as suggested in a comment.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Y3JXD/1/

```
item.Name = ko.computed(function () { return 'Item_' + item.Id(); }, item);
```

Here's another technique for wrapping the reference in a closure, and capturing the right `item` instance (just as a demonstration for what needs to happen to capture the proper scope).

```
self.loadItems = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        var item = ko.mapping.fromJS({
            Id: i
        });
        self.items.push(item);
        (function (item) {
            item.Name = ko.computed(function () {
                return 'Item_' + item.Id();
            });
        })(item);
    }
};
```

Comment: There is a easier sysntax:  `item.Name = ko.computed(function () {
                return 'Item_' + this.Id();
            },item);` you can pass a second parameter to ko.computed and it will the `this` inside the computed.

Comment: D'oh! Good point. I totally forgot about that. Too many JS libraries with too many techniques some days! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you move the `Name` property to the `itemModel`?

```
self.Name = ko.computed(function() { 
    return 'Item_' + self.Id();
});
```

It seems odd to set it when you create the object, rather than when you consume it.

Comment: to the `itemModel`. I'd replace line 41 of your fiddle with the code in my answer